# How to change the type of transitions between slides in this jquery slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone help me to change the type of transitions between slides in this jquery slider ?
I am using a slider called blueberry made ​​by Mark Tyrrell , but wanted the deslizacem slides to the left .

```js
(function($){
 $.fn.extend({
  blueberry: function(options) {

   //default values for plugin options
   var defaults = {
    interval: 5000,
    duration: 500,
    
    lineheight: 1,
    height: 'auto', //reserved
    hoverpause: false,
    pager: true,
    nav: true, //reserved
    keynav: true
   }
   var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
 
   return this.each(function() {
    var o = options;
    var obj = $(this);

    //store the slide and pager li
    var slides = $('.slides li', obj);
    var pager = $('.pager li', obj);

    //set initial current and next slide index values
    var current = 0;
    var next = current+1;

    //get height and width of initial slide image and calculate size ratio
    var imgHeight = slides.eq(current).find('img').height();
    var imgWidth = slides.eq(current).find('img').width();
    var imgRatio = imgWidth/imgHeight;

    //define vars for setsize function
    var sliderWidth = 0;
    var cropHeight = 0;

    //hide all slides, fade in the first, add active class to first slide
    slides.hide().eq(current).fadeIn(o.duration).addClass('active');
    

    //build pager if it doesn't already exist and if enabled
    if(pager.length) {
     pager.eq(current).addClass('active');
    } else if(o.pager){
     obj.append('<ul class="pager"></ul>');
     slides.each(function(index) {
      $('.pager', obj).append('<li><a href="#"><span>'+index+'</span></a></li>')
     });
     pager = $('.pager li', obj);
     pager.eq(current).addClass('active');
    }

    //rotate to selected slide on pager click
    if(pager){
     $('a', pager).click(function() {
      //stop the timer
      clearTimeout(obj.play);
      //set the slide index based on pager index
      next = $(this).parent().index();
      //rotate the slides
      rotate();
      return false;
     });
    }

    //primary function to change slides
    var rotate = function(){
     //fade out current slide and remove active class,
     //fade in next slide and add active class
     slides.eq(current).fadeOut(o.duration).removeClass('active')
      .end().eq(next).fadeIn(o.duration).addClass('active').queue(function(){
       //add rotateTimer function to end of animation queue
       //this prevents animation buildup caused by requestAnimationFrame
       //rotateTimer starts a timer for the next rotate
       rotateTimer();
       $(this).dequeue()
     });

     //update pager to reflect slide change
     if(pager){
      pager.eq(current).removeClass('active')
       .end().eq(next).addClass('active');
     }

     //update current and next vars to reflect slide change
     //set next as first slide if current is the last
     current = next;
     next = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
    };
    //create a timer to control slide rotation interval
    var rotateTimer = function(){
     obj.play = setTimeout(function(){
      //trigger slide rotate function at end of timer
      rotate();
     }, o.interval);
    };
    //start the timer for the first time
    rotateTimer();

    //pause the slider on hover
    //disabled by default due to bug
    if(o.hoverpause){
     slides.hover(function(){
      //stop the timer in mousein
      clearTimeout(obj.play);
     }, function(){
      //start the timer on mouseout
      rotateTimer();
     });
    }

    //calculate and set height based on image width/height ratio and specified line height
    var setsize = function(){
     sliderWidth = $('.slides', obj).width();
     cropHeight = Math.floor(((sliderWidth/imgRatio)/o.lineheight))*o.lineheight;

     $('.slides', obj).css({height: cropHeight});
    };
    setsize();

    //bind setsize function to window resize event
    $(window).resize(function(){
     setsize();
    });
    
    

    //Add keyboard navigation

    if(o.keynav){
     $(document).keyup(function(e){

      switch (e.which) {

       case 39: case 32: //right arrow & space

        clearTimeout(obj.play);

        rotate();

        break;


       case 37: // left arrow
        clearTimeout(obj.play);
        next = current - 1;
        rotate();

        break;
      }

     });
    }


   });
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.blueberry { margin: 0 auto; }
.blueberry .slides {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.blueberry .slides li {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.blueberry .slides li img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
}
.blueberry .slides li.active { display: block; position: relative; }
.blueberry .crop li img { width: auto; }

.blueberry .pager {
 height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
}
.blueberry .pager li { display: inline-block; }
.blueberry .pager li a,
.blueberry .pager li a span {
 display: block;
 height: 4px;
 width: 4px;
}
.blueberry .pager li a {
 padding: 18px 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
   -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
.blueberry .pager li a span {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #c0c0c0;
 text-indent: -9999px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.blueberry .pager li.active a span { background: #404040; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$('.blueberry').blueberry()
});
</script>



<Title>Slides</title>

</head>

<body> 
<div id="doc">
  <div id="cont-slider">
   <div class="blueberry">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li>
                  <img src="http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/img/slide3.jpg"/>
                  </li>
    <li><img src="http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/img/slide4.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/img/slide1.jpg"/></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 
 </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this plugin not support another transition yet

Comment: Why don't you ask Mark Tyrrell?